# how to import a module more then one time

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, import, module

I'm creating a script which can find movies from more than one site and play the movie with subtitle : server.py have all the information how to find the websites that have movies and the file have more than one function. Then I created a folder in the same directory with the server.py. This folder holds more the one website.py this files have the rules how to locate the movie file from the movie website my problem is that I'm importing functions from the server.py to this files exp : (
"""import server
      server.org_link""") when I import the same function to the second file I get an error (AttributeError: module 'server' have no attribute 'org_link')
when I remove from the second file and I run server.py all work normally 
(I cant find out what the problem is)

```
import os
import subprocess
import server  # im importing this to the second file 
from selenium import webdriver as wb
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

option = Options()
option.headless = True
"""Set option headless to use with firefox"""

browser = wb.Firefox(options=option)
"""Set The browser WebDriver FireFox"""

with browser as driver:
     driver.get(server.org_link)
     element = driver.find_element_by_id('DtsBlkVFQx').get_attribute('innerHTML')
     movie_link = server.hosted_server + '/stream/' + element

     if os.name != 'nt':
           vlc = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join("vlc"),os.path.join(movie_link)])
     else:
        vlc = subprocess.Popen([os.path.join("C:/", "Program Files(x86)", "VideoLAN", "VLC", "vlc.exe"), os.path.join(movie_link)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make:
server.org_link()

Instead of:
server.org_link